# Increasing GPS accuracy

Tags: python, gps, signal

I'm using a NEO-6M UART GPS unit and a Python script to record GPS data as latitude and longitude. However, it says accuracy 2.5 meters but I am not getting accuracy at that level.

Connected satellite number is 9. I get the location every one seconds. However, the accuracy of the locations that I get is about 40 meters.

I'm using pynmea2 to parse NMEA data. The data is taken from RMC and GGA. I searched the internet about increasing the accuracy by calculation but couldn't found any related information yet. Is there any source or recommendation to increase my GPS accuracy?

I have a cylindrical dipole antenna.

Comment: Your chipset is quite old. It might due the power mode or a number of other items. Would you consider a BCM47765 Second Generation Dual-Frequency GNSS chipset? https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/gnss-gps-socs/bcm47765 
 as simultaneously supports GPS, GLONASS, NAVIC, BeiDou, Galileo, SBAS, and QZSS in both the L1/ B1/E1 and L5/E5a/B2a frequency bands

Comment: @Mapperz I am also have adafruit ultimate gps v3. does it can be a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Neo-6M but I have worked with Neo-6T, M8N, and M8T modules extensively.  Even with not-very-good antenna, the accuracy is generally in the 3M - 5M range.  I don't think I ever saw position errors as high as 40M, even in poor GPS conditions.

If you are comparing the uBlox position with a reference Latitude / Longitude, I think it's likely that your reference position is in some local reference frame / datum (for example NAD-83 in the USA) not in WGS-84 / ITRF2014 current epoch which is what uBlox will give you.

A good estimate for the accuracy of your GPS is seeing how repeatable the position is - put the antenna on the same feature a few times a day for a few days or weeks and see how much the position varies.  If you take 20 position measurements and they are all within 10M of each other, then you have a reference frame or datum problem not poor GPS accuracy.